# wso2 BRS error after deployment in console

Tags: wso2, esb

I tried this link and succeed deployed but while executing via BRS console i could not get output. Give me some sample link for java programs and drools program. I used following link
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/05/eclipse-plugin-wso2-business-rules-server/

Answer (score 0):

Sample guide is available at http://docs.wso2.org/display/BRS200/BRS+Samples

Try out the samples in BRS distribution - wso2brs/samples location.

Thanks

Thilini